# Java - Finding duplicate entries in multiple arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I wish to find unique points in a bunch of Point arrays (i.e. removing all the duplicates and seeing what is left).

Here is the code I have tried:

```
int numCount = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < ALLARRAYS.length; x++) {
        for (final Point test : ALLARRAYS[x]) {
            NUMBER: for (final Point[] numbers : ALLARRAYS) {
                if (numbers == ALLARRAYS[x]) {
                    continue;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                    if (test.equals(numbers[i])) {
                        break NUMBER;
                    } else {
                        if (i == numbers.length - 1) {
                            numCount++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (numCount == 10) {
                System.out.println(x + "\tPoint: " + test.x + ", " + test.y + " is unique.");
            }
            numCount = 0;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Basically, I have eleven arrays I want to check, therefore the numCount checks for 10 arrays to be confirmed. My approach was to cycle through each array, then cycle through all the points in that array, and then cycle through each point in every other array. If it sees a duplicate, it skips the whole number entirely.

**My problem:** I am getting false readings. I am not sure what is going on, but the program spits out points that already exist in other arrays.

**My goal:** Each array works as a whole. If one element is not satisfied, then the whole array is skipped. My end result should be 11 smaller-in-size arrays that are all unique so that a method can check through the elements of each set and determine that they are all unique.

NOTE: The arrays are all unique now, they are just ridiculously huge. I am looking for a way to truncate it by creating this mini-program to eliminate duplicates.

**My question:** Can someone please help me out?

Comment: What is your question? Is this code working as you expect, or is there something wrong with it?

Comment: Well, I am getting false readings. The points it spits out occur other times in other arrays.

Comment: Could you provide some sample input, actual output, and expected output so that we can help figure out the reason that's happening?

Comment: Would you like the actual code, or just a small example?

Comment: A small example that demonstrates the problem would be sufficient.

Comment: `test == numbers[i]`. Point is a class, comparing it using the `==` operator is only going to return true if `test` and `numbers[i]` have references that are the same. Try using `test.equals(numbers[i])` instead?

Comment: You'll also need to account for the case that compares a `Point` to itself.

Comment: @AdamLiss An excellent point, otherwise you'll never get any identified as unique.

Comment: @leonbloy I got complaints from earlier posts saying that I was too pushy, so I tried to lighten up. -___-

Comment: UPDATE: I now use `test.equals(numbers[i])` instead of `test == numbers[i]`. I now get NO results!

Comment: See @AdamLiss's comment - you need to ignore the situation where you're comparing an element to itself.

Comment: Comparing an element to itself is the idea of removing duplicates ;) . Comparing an Array of Points to itself should be avoided.

Comment: If your arrays are "ridiculously huge," consider sorting them.  Then you can skip to the next array as soon as you encounter a point that occurs after the one you're testing.

Comment: With `n` arrays, each with `p` points, this algorithm is O((np)^2).  For efficiency, you need only compare the 2nd array to the 1st, then the 3rd to the 1st and 2nd, the 4th to the first 3; and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears to check *all* arrays for the `Point` in question, including the array in which the `Point` you're looking for appears. So, your code will always find the `Point` it's looking for, and you will end up with no results.

You may need to do something like this:

```
        NUMBER: for (final Point[] numbers : ALLARRAYS) {
            if (numbers == array) {
                continue; // skip the array that contains 'test'
            }
            ...
        }
```

That way, you will skip the array that contains the `test` element.

Comment: @JavaCoder-1337 Greg's edit should cover it, provided you don't have any duplicate Points in a single array that you want to ignore.

Comment: Your suggestion helped, but still gave me some duplicates. I have edited my original post including my current code.

Comment: The bulletproof answer is to test `(numbers == array && test == numbers[i])` in the inner loop.  But why use two different styles of `for` loop?  No need for the counter `i`.  Re: being "too pushy," just be polite, and if you're asking entry-level questions you may want to reconsider "JavaCoder" and "1337" as a handle.

Comment: @JavaCoder-1337: Ok, so you've (a) moved the goalposts, invalidating the existing answers, and (b) continued to fail to provide sample data that demonstrates your problem. At this point we're having an increasingly difficult time replicating your problem, since we don't have all the information you do.

Answer (score 2):

Put all arrays entries in a Set, it will skip the duplicates.

Just be sure to correctly override the equals method on your Point class because the implementations of Set interface will use it.

HTH

Comment: that can work if he wants the union of the arrays in a new array

Comment: I am not looking for this. Please use my example above.

Comment: I think a better approach would be to put the entries into a map from _entry_ to _number of times entry appeared in the arrays_. The key could be an `Integer` or, if you're worried about object allocation, a mutable `Integer`-type class. Once you have the Map created, you can iterate over the Map entries and get the ones whose count is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays aren't well suited for your job. Not only that they don't don't have methods like intersection or removeAll, they are hard to change, especially if you want to reduce their size.

To avoid this hassle, I mark a Point as `removed` by setting x and y to -1, one coordinate would of course be enough, but for reasons of symmetry ...

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Point;

public class RandPoints
{
    Random r = new Random ();
    Point [][] arr;

    public void removeDuplicatesFrom2 (Point [] pa, Point [] pb) {
        for (Point p : pb) {
            if (p.x != - 1 && Arrays.asList (pa).contains (p)) {
                // System.out.println ("dup: " + p.x + " " + p.y);
                p.x = -1;
                p.y = -1;
            }
        }
    }

    // create a random point in range (0..19)(0..19)
    public Point randpoint () {
        return new Point (r.nextInt (20), r.nextInt (20));
    }

    // create 10 (default) arrays of size 100 (default)
    public void init (int arrsize, int arrcount) 
    {
        arr = new Point [arrcount][];
        for (int c = 0; c < arrcount; ++c)
        {
            Point [] points = new Point [arrsize];
            for (int s = 0; s < arrsize; ++s)
            {
                Point p = randpoint ();
                points[s] = p; 
            }
            arr[c] = points;
        }
    }

    public void unify () 
    {
        for (Point[] pac0 : arr) {
            for (Point[] pac1 : arr) 
            {
                if (pac0 != pac1)
                removeDuplicatesFrom2 (pac0, pac1);     
            }   
        }
    }

    /**
        fill arrays with duplicates by random, 
        show, delete and show again.
    */
    public RandPoints (int arrsize, int arrcount)
    {
        init (arrsize, arrcount);
        show ();
        unify (); 
        System.out.println ();
        show ();
    }

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        int arrsize = 100;
        int arrcount = 10;
        if (args.length == 2)
        {
            arrsize = Integer.parseInt (args[0]);
            arrcount = Integer.parseInt (args[1]);
        }
        new RandPoints (arrsize, arrcount);
    }

    // visible feedback is always welcome while debugging/testing
    public void show ()
    {
        for (Point[] pa: arr) {
            for (Point point: pa)
                if (point.x != -1 && point.y != -1)
                    System.out.print (point.x + ", " + point.y + "\t");
            System.out.println ();
        }
    }
}
```

I modified the code a bit, to make the maximum range for the values (20) configurable too.

Starting it with

```
java RandPoints 16 10 10
3, 0    9, 0    6, 9    2, 3    6, 9    7, 4    9, 9    2, 5    8, 7    3, 3    9, 5    3, 7    0, 5    7, 6    0, 4    8, 1    
6, 1    2, 7    2, 5    6, 7    0, 7    5, 8    4, 2    1, 9    8, 4    5, 7    0, 2    3, 1    1, 9    2, 1    8, 0    1, 7    
5, 4    9, 7    9, 3    7, 3    1, 2    9, 6    0, 4    6, 0    3, 0    7, 7    1, 3    1, 1    5, 3    3, 8    1, 0    4, 9    
4, 7    8, 9    4, 0    0, 2    8, 7    5, 8    7, 0    1, 4    4, 9    8, 2    6, 9    9, 6    2, 1    1, 9    0, 8    6, 5    
6, 8    9, 6    1, 0    6, 9    4, 0    5, 1    2, 9    7, 3    5, 1    2, 5    6, 9    0, 9    7, 4    8, 1    5, 5    3, 4    
5, 9    0, 4    5, 4    2, 2    2, 6    7, 1    2, 0    6, 1    0, 4    9, 8    5, 7    5, 5    4, 6    9, 0    2, 8    8, 5    
8, 2    4, 2    0, 8    1, 1    0, 3    3, 4    1, 8    3, 1    6, 6    4, 1    3, 6    6, 0    1, 7    4, 8    1, 6    1, 1    
6, 2    1, 3    2, 4    0, 8    9, 0    3, 0    1, 1    3, 7    6, 2    2, 4    0, 9    3, 6    7, 2    1, 2    5, 0    8, 2    
2, 3    5, 6    7, 9    3, 0    9, 3    2, 6    4, 8    8, 7    9, 4    5, 3    0, 3    3, 0    5, 5    1, 4    6, 4    5, 2    
3, 2    4, 9    6, 9    4, 7    7, 1    0, 4    5, 8    7, 2    5, 2    5, 5    2, 1    9, 8    4, 9    6, 6    7, 7    0, 3    

3, 0    9, 0    6, 9    2, 3    6, 9    7, 4    9, 9    2, 5    8, 7    3, 3    9, 5    3, 7    0, 5    7, 6    0, 4    8, 1    
6, 1    2, 7    6, 7    0, 7    5, 8    4, 2    1, 9    8, 4    5, 7    0, 2    3, 1    1, 9    2, 1    8, 0    1, 7    
5, 4    9, 7    9, 3    7, 3    1, 2    9, 6    6, 0    7, 7    1, 3    1, 1    5, 3    3, 8    1, 0    4, 9    
4, 7    8, 9    4, 0    7, 0    1, 4    8, 2    0, 8    6, 5    
6, 8    5, 1    2, 9    5, 1    0, 9    5, 5    3, 4    
5, 9    2, 2    2, 6    7, 1    2, 0    9, 8    4, 6    2, 8    8, 5    
0, 3    1, 8    6, 6    4, 1    3, 6    4, 8    1, 6    
6, 2    2, 4    6, 2    2, 4    7, 2    5, 0    
5, 6    7, 9    9, 4    6, 4    5, 2    
3, 2
```